# How do you set the density for mdc-icon-button using mixins?

Tags: sass, material-components-web

I'm pretty new to using sass and I'm having some trouble using a mixin for [Material.io's icon buttons.](https://material.io/develop/web/components/buttons/icon-buttons/)
The page I linked describes using the `density($density-scale)` mixin, but I can't seem to figure out how to use it. The [Getting Started](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/) guide shows an example of how to use a mixin for an `mdc-button`, so I tried doing the same thing for an `mdc-icon-button`. Here are some things I tried.

```
@use "@material/icon-button/mdc-icon-button";
@use "@material/icon-button";
// ^ The line above results in this error: SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
```

For the actual element, since this import didn't work, I tried the following.

```
.mdc-icon-button {
    @include icon-button.density(-1);
    // ^ SassError: There is no module with the namespace "icon-button".
    @include mdc-icon-button.density(-1);
    @include mdc-icon-button-density(-1);
    @include density(-1);
    // ^ All of these lines cause the following error: SassError: Undefined mixin.
}
```

I'm just not sure what to do at this point. How can I use the density mixin for this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually turns out to be a bug with `sass-loader`. You can check [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/804) for a temporary workaround while something else is worked out. Using the workaround causes imports to not fail anymore, and the documentation is still accurate for the components.